# Add more packages to the default installation with Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

When Linux is installed, (I assume) a bash script is used to mount the drive, install packages, etc. etc. If I wanted to install more packages upon installation, what directory would the script to install Linux be in? Also, is it written in bash?

I would like to add packages and change the configuration (using the `dconf write` command in terminal) upon installation for my Linux Mint derivative.

Comment: This is dependent on the distribution you're installing, and it usually isn't a `bash` script.

Comment: Here's an interesting link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Installer/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a custom installer that installs a different set of packages.

The following information pertains to the Debian installer (known as d-i). Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian and also uses d-i, plus it also supports another installer called Ubiquity, which can be automated [in a different way](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation). For more information see this [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Installer/FAQ). I am not familiar with Mint but it is a derivative of Ubuntu so what applies to Ubuntu may also apply to Mint. If not, someone else may add a better answer which is specific to Mint.

The main supported way of doing this in d-i is through a [preseed](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) file. Preseed files allow you to (optionally) answer in advance every question that the installer would normally ask during installation, allowing for a fully automated experience, all without making any modifications to the installer itself. But in addition to or instead of providing automated answers to questions, a preseed file can also customize the list of packages to be installed. The primary use case is to save work in environments where many identical computers are to be installed. Creating a preseed file takes work but after that you can deploy it for example in your PXE server together with the rest of the installer components and perform hands-off installations of hundreds of computers or more.

There are also ways to [modify](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify) the Debian installer without using a preseed file so that it will install different packages. This requires care because you need to unpackage the installer, mount it, make modifications, and repackage it in the very special way that makes the installer versatile and usable as either a CD image, a USB storage device image, or a net-bootable image.

> what directory would the script to install Linux be in?

The Debian [Ubuntu, Mint] installer is not one single script but a collection of components, some written in C, others shell scripts. It's very hookable and pluggable, so you should be able to customize it fully without modifying any part of it, only writing hooks (generally shell scripts) and configuration files for it.

> Also, is it written in bash?

No. `bash` is not available in the installer environment, only Busybox's `/bin/sh`. But you usually don't need `bash` anyway. The POSIX-like Busybox shell has to suffice.

> how would i configure packages within the preseed?

Packages are responsible for configuring themselves when they get installed. That's true whether they're installed during initial system installation or later once the system is up. They contain scripts like `postinst` to do jobs like that. However, actually, most packages don't configure anything at all, they just install themselves (i.e. they don't have any `postinst`). The installer itself only does the bare minimum system configuration (like setting the host name and a root password). The result is that everything pretty much has its default configuration (= no configuration) after the system is installed.

Having said that, you can cause the installer to run commands from the preseed script, like this:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    command1; \
    in-target command2; \
    command3
```

(That's a single long shell command with backslashed to split the line in pieces.)

Those commands can do whatever you need them to do. Note how I prefixed one of the commands with `in-target`: that makes it run inside the just-installed environment instead of in the installer environment.

If you have more work to do then is practical using this method, my suggestion is to create your own package (`xxx.deb`) which acts as your local configuration virtual package and, when installed, customized the enrivonment in whatever way you like. The advantage of that is that you can also install that package on a system that has not been installed using your customized installer (perhaps it has been installed using the default installer), and get the benefit.

> how would i install and configure themes for mint

I don't know. Are themes contained in packages? That would be nice because then you could just add those packages to the list. Otherwise, consider packaging them.

You can host your own APT repository for any local custom packages that you do create. You get to specify your local repository in the pressed file (with `d-i apt-setup/[...]`) so the installer knows where to pick up your packages.

Comment: Ubuntu has its own installer, Ubiquity. It too can be preseeded, but [in a different way](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation). I think Mint also uses Ubiquity.

Comment: @Gilles In one place I work at we use d-i, with preseeding, to install Ubuntu. I didn't know about Ubiquity. The [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Installer/FAQ) linked in one of the comments on the question says both are supported. If Mint uses Ubiquity and does not support d-i then unfortunately I guess my answer is useless for Mint.

Comment: how would i configure packages within the preseed? all i have seen is how to install additional packages. also, how would i install and configure themes for mint?

Comment: @user3502615 answer edited to add that information